# TF.keras.metrics.AUC does not work on multiclass

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass problems.
Three classes with labels 0 1 and 2.

If I create a model netowrk and I run this at the end

```
model.add(Activation('softmax')) 
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy',tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name = 'auc')])
```

I always receive immediately the error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

If I remove

```
tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name = 'auc')
```

from the metrics everything works.

I read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC) about `tf.keras.metrics.AUC` and it should work in the case of multi-class, but to me it does not.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!